# Table view width base on number rows issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4.2

I have a issue with height table view, for example if I have 3 rows in a table view and each row has 50 , table view will be 150 (I have a table view inside table view, the issue is in the second table), for both table view cells I load a custom cell from xib, I attach a xib inside table view cell   
This is my first table view

[image]

This is the xib for the fist table view, second table view is inside, I set bottom relation greater or equal

[image]

This is the first view code:

```
class QuestionList: UIView{
  
  @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  @IBOutlet weak var tableViewHC: NSLayoutConstraint!
  
  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    commonInit()
    setTableView()
  }
  
  func commonInit(){
    let viewFromXib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("QuestionList", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! UIView
    viewFromXib.frame = self.bounds
    questionLabel.normalGray()
    addSubview(viewFromXib)
  }
  func setTableView(){
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "AnswerListTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "answerListCell")
    
    tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    tableViewHC.constant = CGFloat(150 * 3)
  }
  
  
}

extension QuestionList: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
  }
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
  }
  
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "answerListCell", for: indexPath) as! AnswerListTableViewCell
    cell.separatorInset.right = cell.separatorInset.left
    cell.answerList.optionLabel.text = "Text Text"
    return cell
  }
}
```

This is the second xib for the second table view

[image]

This is the second view code:

```
class AnswerList: UIView {

 @IBOutlet weak var optionSwitch: UISwitch!
 @IBOutlet weak var optionLabel: UILabel!
 
 required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
   super.init(coder: coder)
   commonInit()
 }
 
 func commonInit(){
   let viewFromXib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AnswerList", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! UIView
   viewFromXib.frame = self.bounds
   optionLabel.normalGray()
   addSubview(viewFromXib)
 }
 

}
```

This my output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want tableview height to be of it's content, calculate that in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    tabelView.height = tableView.contentSize.height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is a taller tableView what you want to achieve to fix this?
If so, you can probably change the tableView's heightEquals to something bigger than your current = 160.

You can also calculate and set the tableView to a different height like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 80
}
```

Comment: No I want to achieve a tableview with height dynamic NO dynamic heigh for at row @JohnKasich_2016

Comment: @LgSus97 : Check my answer. hope this is what you are looking for...